# ASP.Net GridView - how to get selected column Index (in Dynamic Gridview)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have n number of dynamically generated GridViews in my asp.net page. In all the GridView all the cells are linkbuttons which also dynamically generated. And I want to get selected cells/ linkbuttons index.

How do i do it?

**Note-** I dont have GridView name as it is dynamically generated in loop.

code as below-

```
Protected Sub Btncalculate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Btncalculate.Click      
Call GetFinal()
End Sub

Public Sub GetFinal()
 For count As Integer = 0 To dtValue.Rows.Count - 1
Dim GrdView1 As New GridView()

'DataTable filling Code goes here

GrdView1.DataSource = dt1

AddHandler GrdView1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf GrdView1_SelectedIndexChanged
AddHandler GrdView1.RowDataBound, AddressOf GrdView1_RowDataBound
AddHandler GrdView1.RowCommand, AddressOf GrdView1_RowCommand
GrdView1.DataBind()
end sub

Public Sub GrdView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

' All cell to LinkButton code goes here

AddHandler lnkShow.Click, AddressOf LinkButton1_Click
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You create linkButtons

```
Public Sub GrdView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        LinkButton lnkShow= new LinkButton();
        lnkShow.Text = "Show";
        lnkShow.CommandArgument = "Show";
        lnkShow.CommandArgument = e.Row.Cell(0); ' For instance
    End IF
End Sub
```

And then you handle the GridView1.RowCommand event:

```
Public Sub GrdView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)        
    If e.CommandName = "show" Then
        LinkButton lnkShow= (LinkButton)sender;
        argument = e.CommandArgument;
        (do something)
    End IF
End Sub
```

I thoink you dont need Link1_Click

Comment: Hi user3077371, thanks for your reply but i want index of the selected cell/column. I have done the said part.